# Using a single MOSFET to switch current direction

Tags: arduino, mosfet, dc-motor

I am currently using a 30N06L MOSFET in order to control a DC engine from an Arduino using this circuit:

[image: circuit]

The problem is that this way I cannot change the direction of the engine.

Is there a way to also be able to change the direction of the engine (e.g change the direction of the current), using another MOSFET? We have only 2 mosfets, and do not have any special drivers..

Maybe it is possible to connect another similar circuit (in parallel to this one), with the voltage switching legs in the second mosfet, and then by controlling that mosfet turning the engine in the other direction?

Thanks.

Comment: You'll want to use an H-Bridge, but it will take 4 MOSFETs to implement rather than just 2. They are available in a single IC package, but I can't think of a DIP style package off hand. Perhaps someone else can suggest one?

Comment: You could do it with just one addtional MOSFET if you have a second (negative) power supply available. But then, you'll have to deal with level-shifting issues in order to drive its gate. (Additional small-signal transistors)

Comment: I'd have to ditto the above comments. Without a second (negative) power supply or at least 4 MOSFETs, you are stuck to one direction. Although, if they are logic level MOSFETs (low gate voltage threshold) you don't need to worry about the level shifting to drive the gates.

Comment: @KurtE.Clothier: Think about it carefully -- if you have two (or four) identical transistors driving this motor, either from dual supplies or in an H-bridge configuration, how would you drive their gates from the same MCU without requiring level shifters of some sort on at least half of them?

Comment: @Dave Tweed: Ah, you are right. I was just thinking about 4 MOSFETs, not necessarily 4 "identical" MOSFETs - darn those P channels. I'm off my game today...

Answer (score 2):

If you can lower your 60V requirement to more like 20V and 0.5A, you can look at a [motor shield](http://www.ladyada.net/make/mshield/). These implement an H-bridge which gives you optimum control over your motor. Actually it has 4 H-bridges, so you need only a single shield for 4 motors.

There are bound to be other motor shields, maybe some of those have higher output specifications.